# How can I get values except for NULL using SQLAlchem?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like to get values except for NULL.
Here's example.

```
from sqlalchemy import select
select([table]).execute().fetchone()
 -> ('1', 'some value', 'some value', None, None)
```

I don't want to get `None`.
Is there any way to get values except for NULL?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning you all columns by default. You should select only the columns you want to avoid the extra NULL/None values.

[The docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) have more info on that. Since you are passing the whole table you get all the columns.

Comment: Thanks. When I select all columns including NULL/None values, is there any way to automatically skip NULL/None values? I want exactly this function.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental feature of SQL is that a query returns the same number of columns for each row, so there's no way *not* to return a column based on some per-row condition on the SQL side. SQLAlchemy just follows this logic.

If you want to exclude None values from the data returned by SQLAlchemy, you can do it in Python:

```
def no_nulls(row):
    return [column for column in row if column is not None]

no_nulls(select([table]).execute().fetchone())
 -> ('1', 'some value', 'some value')
```

If a column is NULL in some rows but not in others, this approach may return different number of elements for different rows.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use function like this.